# git folder not visible

Tags: git, github

i ran into a typical situation.
I already have a cloned repo in my local. and i have a path /src/main/resources

my goal was to create a directory inside resources and name it scripts and add some files into that folder.
what i did was i created a folder and copied the files but when adding these items to github i added only the files and forgot to add the folders. i created myself a pull request and merged it to develop.

now this whole set of files are not visible in the remote repo.
also in local if i now go to src/main/resources/scripts and do git add . nothing is happening.

please help me how to recover from this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You don't add folders with Git, only files (which are in folders).

Check first how many .git subfolder you have:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
find . -type d -name ".git"
```

That will detect if you have any nested repository.

And do a git status in `/src`, and `/src/main/resources` (assuming here that `/src` means actually `/path/to/local/repository/src`)

Answer (score 0):

Empty directories or folders cannot be committed. That is why the empty directory you created was not visible in the remote.

You should either add a .gitignore or a .gitkeep inside the empty directory to be able to commit and view that in the remote.

[How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)